# Using Socket.IO in MeteorJS Server

Tags: node.js, meteor, socket.io, server

i am trying top get socket.io working from the MeteorJS server. i am using the package from https://github.com/joncursi/socket-io-client, but i am unable to get it to work from the server and i cant figure out why.

i call the "connectToServer" method from the client, then this should contact the remote server and initialise the connection. when the code executes, i can see that the messages being logged, but nothing inside the "socket.on('connect',..." method. this suggests that it isn't making the connection. this is backed up by the fact that when i run code from the client side (using the the socket.io browser javascript code), i am able to connect without issues.

i have code on the server, whever there is an attempt to connect to the socket.io connection. this logged, with the client side code but not the server side code.

can anyone see what i may be doing wrong here?

```
Meteor.methods({
    'connectToServer': function() {
        socketioController();
    }
});

function socketioController(){

    var username = 'asd';
    var password = 'asd';
    console.log("trying to login with asd");

    var socket = io('https://localhost:3001/');
    console.log("socket variable set");

    socket.on('connect', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
        console.log('Connected to the websocket!');
        //Meteor.call('methodName1');

        // on data event
        socket.on('data-event', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            Meteor.call('methodName2');
        }, function(e) {
            throw e;
        }));

        // on disconnect
        socket.on('disconnect', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
          console.log('Disconnected from the websocket!');
          Meteor.call('methodName3');
        }, function(e) {
          throw e;
        }));

    }, function(e) {
        throw e;
    }));

}
```

Comment: just to debug a little bit, you should also add events for `error` and `close` and see if it is doing either of those.

Comment: I'll add those because it's a good idea, but those listeners haven't made any difference. "connected to web socket" should be logged regardless of those events.